# What's wrong with my Click Code Event button in visual studio to open a specific file.exe?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process jcam = new Process();
        jcam.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\JasminCam Five\App\JCam-main.exe";
        jcam.Start();
    }
```

This is my code for the Click Event, but it get s the next error : Not Found The Configuration File

Comment: Where specifically do you have a problem: Adding a button, or adding your code to the Click event handler?

Comment: The problem is with my code to the Click event, i added the button, but i get an error when i press it, basically it doesnt do what i need it to do.

Comment: Can you show your Click event code and tell us **which** error you get?

Comment: Well the code is the one i posted upper, unfortunately that code get's an error ( Not found the configuration file)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make this clear. Also, please include the exact error message.

Comment: How does the error message appear? Is this an exception, or a pop-up? Is it possible that it's just JCam-main.exe that can't find the configuration file? Are you sure that's the right executable to launch, and that it doesn't need any command-line arguments?

Comment: If you type [Windows]+R and enter "C:\Program Files\JasminCam Five\App\JCam-main.exe" (without the quotes) - what happens? Does the appplication start or do you see an error?

Comment: When i type it in run, it launches the app, there is no error. and about the arguments, i'm not really sure, but i'll check thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible reasons for this error:

1. Your ProgrameFile is an encrypted folder, and you need to change a folder to try this operation. Also you need to check your file paths.
2. UseShellExecute property is true. For example:

   ```
    Process jcam = new Process();
    jcam.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
    ProcessStartInfo pr= jcam.StartInfo;
    pr.UseShellExecute= true;
    jcam.Start();
   ```